# Dynamically created image layout

Tags: html, image, layout

Using HTML, CSS, and JQuery, and given a set of images with various dimensions, how would I generate an image layout resembling the below?

[image: Desired layout]

[Note:  I don't want to generate *exactly* this layout - I know how to construct it in HTML with tables and rowspan/colspan (ugly), but how programmatically, and nicely?]

I really have no idea how to approach this, as HTML is rather box-row-column-based, and this is sort of stepping out of that. Is there a way to look at it that makes it easier to program?
(perhaps absolute positioning and just bashing out the computations?)

A follow-up question might be how to avoid the problem of inevitably inexact dimensions. It would be fine to have something like that below, just as long as everything's lined up and square with each other.

[image: Alternate layout]

Answer (score 0):

Using css `position` is the easy way as long as you have static image data here i.e. you have the images and they will not change. The only harm here is that you would have to calculate the positions manually.

Just make a "holder" `div` and give it css `position: relative`, then the inner stuff `position: absolute`:

```
<div id=""holder>
  <img id="image1" />
  <img id="image2" />
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

css:

```
#holder {
  position: relative;
}
#image1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: **distance from top goes here**;
  left: **distance from left**;
}
```